# My MvvmCross binding keeps failing

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following two bindings on a button in my Xamarin Android app:

```
 local:MvxBind="{'Enabled':{'Path':'PlayerName.Length'}, 'Click':{'Path':'Commands[CreatePlayerCommand]'}}"
```

Basically I'm trying to enable/disable a button based on the length of a text in my ViewModel. I'm also bind the Click to a command.

But it keeps failing. Is there something wrong with the syntax???

Here are some of the errors I see:

> MvxBind:Error:  2.56 Problem parsing binding MvxException:
>   PropertyName must start with letter - position 0 in
>   {'Click':{'Path':'Commands[CreatePlayerCommand]'}} - char {
>
> MvxBind:Error:  2.57 Failed to parse binding specification starting
>   with {'Click':{'Path':'Co

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

I had to use Swiss notation since for some reason the JSON notation wasn't working  :\

```
 local:MvxBind="Enabled PlayerName.Length; Click CreatePlayerCommand"
```